# Compare two strings as in strcmp error error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

Tags: c, pointers, comparison, c-strings

I am trying to write a C function that compares tho strings not as pointer equality but content equality. But I get an error

> error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int stringcompare(char * str1, char * str2, int strSize){
  char * word1 = str1;
  char * word2 = str2;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < strSize; i++) {
    if (*word1[i] != *word2[i]) {
      printf("The strings are DIFFERENT!");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  printf("The strings are a MATCH!");
  return 0;
}

int main(void){
  char * str1 = "Hello World!";
  char * str2 = "Hello World!";
  stringcompare(str1, str2, 13);
}
```

Comment: What do you understand `*word1[i]` to mean?

Comment: `word1[i]` is an integer value (the array element), so it can't be dereferenced with `*word1[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This if statement

```
if (*word1[i] != *word2[i]) {
```

is incorrect because the expressions `word1[i]` and `word2[i]` have the type `char`. So you may not apply the dereference operator for an object of the type `char`.

You should write for example

```
if ( word1[i] != word2[i]) {
```

Pay attention to that the standard string function `strcmp` has only two parameters and it returns either negative value, or zero or a positive value depending on whether the first string is greater than the second string or is equal to the second string or is less than the second string.

It seems you mean another standard string function `strncmp` that indeed has three parameters..

Also you need to check whether the zero terminating character was already encountered.

Apart from this the function parameters should have the qualifier `const` because the passed strings are not being changed within the function.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
int stringcompare( const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n )
{
    while ( n && *s1 && *s1 == *s2 )
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
        --n;
    }

    return n == 0 ? 0 : *s1 - *s2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For an array, pointed to by `*ptr`, an element at position `i` is dereferenced by `*(ptr + i)`, which is the equivalent of `ptr[i]` and not `*ptr[i]`.